# Angular UI State name causing '$stateNotFound` error

Tags: angular-ui

So I was wiring up my AngularUI State Views using the following code

```
$stateProvider
            .state('dash.landing', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/partials/backup/dash/landing.html',
                controller: 'LandingController'
            })
            .state('dash.order', {
                url: '/overview',
                templateUrl: '/partials/backup/dash/order/index.html',
                controller: 'OrderController'
            })
            .state('dash.order.overview', {
                url: '/overview',
                templateUrl: '/partials/backup/dash/order/overview.html',
                controller: 'OverviewController'
            })
            .state('dash.order.email-accounts', {
                url: '/email-accounts',
                templateUrl: '/partials/backup/dash/order/email-accounts.html'
            })
            .state('dash.order.alerts', {
                url: '/alerts',
                templateUrl: '/partials/backup/dash/order/alerts.html'
            });
```

And for some reason my views were not being rendered and I was getting a `$stateNotFound` error telling me it could not find `dash.landing`. After 15 minutes of pulling my hair out I simply changed `dash.landing' to just be`dash`and all of a sudden it worked perfectly! Can someone please explain why I can't use`dash.landing` for the root route state name?

Comment: Wait...is it because AngularUI actually uses `grandparent.parent.child.grandchild` notation natively? I thought the '.' notation was just an organization practice, but it appears like the state name actually does matter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ui-router uses dot notation to implement parent/child relationships among views. You can use dot notation with the default routeProvider to name routes. You can also use dot notation to name application modules, letting other developers know there is a organizational hierarchy in place.